# How can I find elements using text in a generic way for ios automation using appium?

Tags: python, ios, automation, appium

I am new to ios automation using appium. I am trying to obtain an element based on text in appium automation in python. I am currently obtaining text using following command:

uiel = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//XCUIElementTypeStaticText[@label="abc"]')

Lets say I want to write an api find_element_by_text(string) for IOS, I would have to pass the type of element and string and based on element type I should call, find_element by x_path as shown:

```
           if ios_button:
               uiel = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//XCUIElementTypeButton[@label="'+ aString +'"]')
           elif is_other:
               uiel = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//XCUIElementTypeOther[@label="' + aString + '"]')
           elif is_cell:
               uiel = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//XCUIElementTypeCell[@label="' + aString + '"]')
           else:
               uiel = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//XCUIElementTypeStaticText[@label="' + aString + '"]' )
```

Is there a way to obtain an element in IOS with just one line instead of having all the checks above?

Answer (score 1):

Send your element type as the actual string associated with the type ("Button", "Other", "Cell", "StaticText") and then create your find using concatenation, which you've shown you already understand.

```
uiel = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//XCUIElementType' + myElementType + '[@label="'+ aString +'"]')
```

I've not test run this code; there may be syntax errors, but you should get the idea.

Comment: That is a good suggestion. But my problem is that element type varies for me in every device. Let's say I have an "element x". Its type is XCUIElementTypeOther in ipod whereas it is XCUIElementTypeStaticText in iphone6. So I was wondering if there was generic way to check that

Comment: It's not clear to my why the elements would be different on the same platform, but you're looking for the software to do something that it has no knowledge of how to do. You can still use the idea I suggested, but you're going to have to tell Appium the mappings of your system and choose the correct one depending on the device type.